# Adding a comma separator in Javascript output

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please review the Fiddle [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/webfrogs/3VpYQ/)

In the JS, I have some output for a number. This number is currently without a comma delimiter.

I would like to add a comma in the thousands place.

Here's my output snippet -

```
<input type="text" disabled="disabled" class="savings numbers" id="moneySaved">
```

Here's the JS that goes with that -

```
$("#moneySaved").val("$" +(resultNonNursing*402) + ( " in tuition costs")); //# of credits * cost per credit ($402)
```

I am trying to use the jQuery Number Formatter. I have this in the header -

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $(".numbers").each(function() {
                $(this).format({format:"#,###", locale:"us"});
            });
        });
```

And I've added the `numbers` class to the html output -

```
<input type="text" disabled="disabled" class="savings numbers" id="moneySaved">
```

...but it is not working.

Can you provide some direction here?

Comment: What do you mean, it isn't working? Can you explain what you're getting as a result? I, and many other SO users, can't look at your fiddle, because it's restricted in work.

Comment: Well, I'm not getting the comma separator. The output is `1234` and I'm trying to accomplish `1,234`, or `123,456,789`, and `123`.

Comment: Is it an ordering problem? You're applying the format to all numbers before you set the value. You don't need the .each by the way, you could just use `$('.numbers').format(...)`.

Answer (score 2):

```
Number.prototype.format = function(){
   return this.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1,");
};
```

or if you don't like that

```
anumber.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,");
```

Comment: I'd imagine this is the only case when he's using this format function call, so it's exactly what he'd want.

Comment: your second solution is a lot better

Comment: You can either add the Number.prototype and call format without any arguments (aka number.format();) or you can replace $(this).format({format:"#,###", locale:"us"}); with $(this).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,");

Comment: Here's an updated [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/webfrogs/3VpYQ/). It's not working. I've added it as you suggested. Thoughts?

Comment: your function is on document ready and is not going to fire more than once, you should hook the function up to an event that makes sense, like onkeyup or onchange for the textbox.